# How to get the files from amazon s3 cloud storage

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am using `scandir()` function to scan the directory from the cloud. This function working in the local system but not worked in the sever. I have run this function using php code in the server i het the following error

```
Warning: scandir(https:// xxxx/yyyy/folder/): failed to open dir: No such file or directory

Warning: scandir(): (errno 2): No such file or directory 

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

How to solve this error..

Comment: Did you see the [notes about fopen wrappers here?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access the S3 Bucket for getting files from cloud server..

Refer [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/get_object_url)